# What happened to my edit on "Molecular Gastronomy" question?

Tags: support

Two days ago I edited the title of this question, [What is Molecular Gastronomy?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20090/7000) because it was written "What's is Molecular Gastronomy?"

I see today it was updated, but by someone else, and I don't show up in the edit history.

Did I imagine it, or was it rejected for some reason? I'm not sure where I can find rejected edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a page where you can see the status of your edits. You should start by checking that. To do that go to your account -> Activity -> Suggestions.

I don't see you in the edit history though. I believe a question (or answer) may only have one suggested edit in queue at a time. So if you were second, your edit would not have been submitted. Sounds like that's what happened.